# save recorded video only last 2 minutes

Tags: android

If I take a 10 minute video I would like that only the last 2 minutes of the video will be saved in mobile not the whole 10 minutes. How can I do this??

And how can I do that when recording starts every time when I press the button it will save 2 minute video and then start video recorder when press button it again save 2 minutes video???

```
package com.example.checkvidio;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VideoWithSurfaceVw extends Activity{

//Starter Tutorial: http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/android-video-capture-tutorial.html

private Camera myCamera;
private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
public static int orientation;
Button myButton;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    recording = false;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get Camera for preview
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();

    //myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); //Doesn't error here, but doesn't affect video.

    if(myCamera == null){
        Toast.makeText(VideoWithSurfaceVw.this,
                "Fail to get Camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera,this);
    FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            if(recording){
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

                //Exit after saved
                //finish();
                myButton.setText("REC");
                recording = false;
            }else{

                //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
                releaseCamera();

                if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                    Toast.makeText(VideoWithSurfaceVw.this,
                            "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                mediaRecorder.start();
                recording = true;
                myButton.setText("STOP");
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }};

private Camera getCameraInstance(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(0); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}


private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // set the orientation here to enable portrait recording.
    setCameraDisplayOrientation(this,0,myCamera);

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    myCamera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo1.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50Mb

mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(VideoWithSurfaceVw.orientation);
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
        mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (myCamera != null){
        myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        myCamera = null;
    }
}

public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera,Activity activity) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mActivity=activity;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        try {
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(mActivity,0,mCamera);
            previewCamera();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void previewCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Log.d(APP_CLASS, "Cannot start preview", e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                               int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {

    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();

    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing`enter code here`
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    VideoWithSurfaceVw.orientation=result;
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put restriction that after 2 mins the video recording gets automatically stopped.
Or if you want to do a video operations like croping or trimming that Android is not providing any APIs for that you have to use third party library like FFMPEG.

Comment: You can find the FFMPEG library and its integration steps in android on googel and stackoverflow itself.
You can find the more about that in some blogs too.
In fact i am also writing a blog about that too. i will post the link here as soon as possible.

Comment: DEAR  Hardik Chauhan i need a video file that continuously start recording  but save video of only 2  minute video continuously and overwrite the data can you ask about that

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you exactly.

Comment: i want my app to continuously record camera video on a file which will be a video file but the length should not exceed more then 2 minutes and when i press stop button and play the video file i get the video of last two minutes of the video recorded at the last time.

Comment: for that you have to use FFMPEG or other video library to crop the last 2 mins video.